# Does Stack Exchange use virtualisation, or focus on more servers?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I just learn that using virtualisation (making one server act as many) saves a (lot) of energy - because of cooling the servers.

The example they gave was that 10 servers at 5% can be set to run on one server, and that is still only at 50%.

Does Stack Exchange use virtualisation for this, or are there many servers the load is split across?

Comment: Did you read: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370)

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes, but it doesn't mention virtualisation.

Comment: You probably want a blog post I wrote here: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/ :)

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks :) Interesting fact, in 1 day you're sending 10x the data sent around the world in 1992 :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uje7.jpg

Comment: Be careful when you hear blanket statements like *"saves a (lot) of energy"* - things are seldom as simple as that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does Stack Exchange use virtualisation for this, or are there many servers the load is split across?

9 physical servers for the Q&A sites.

Putting many servers on one box still means that are sharing CPU(s), memory and bandwidth, meaning that if one is put under load it effects all the others, badly.

Having 10 physical servers means 10x the CPU, memory and bandwidth, which can come really handy ;)

Virtualization is not a panacea - it uses *shared* resources. That can be fine if there is low utilization.

Comment: "which can come really handy" means when you DDoSed yourselves? :P https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/115305251014/outage-postmortem-march-31-2015

Comment: @Tim - more thinking about the time where we crashed 8 of the servers and no one outside the compnay noticed ;)

Comment: Hmm, impressive!

Comment: "we crashed" - yeah, we know it was you :D