# Exactly how much support is required for a feature request to meet the criteria for escalation as per the new procedure?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, community

Looking into the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345032/community-and-moderator-guidelines-for-escalating-issues-via-new-response-proces?cb=1) for requesting escalation on meta posts (i.e. to add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag), it says:

> For any new question posted during the test period (anything posted
>   from March 16, 2020 on), consider the following questions:
>
> - Is the question a feature request that looks like it has community support?
> - Is it a bug report that others have been able to reproduce?
> - Is the question only fully answerable by an employee?
>
> If you replied “yes” to at least one of the above, then that question is a good candidate for escalation.

Recently, I had a couple flags on questions where I *thought* the question met the criteria declined.

One of them was a feature request with a positive score, with the flag raised after a week:

> [image: declined - 10/-3 votes isn't really all that 'positively-received', given other posts easily reach a score of 30 on a single day.]

> declined - 10/-3 votes isn't really all that 'positively-received', given other posts easily reach a score of 30 on a single day.

In my opinion, even though the score may not be +30, it still *looks* like it has community support. However, the moderator handling the flag didn't think it was enough to *look* like it had community support.

So that begs the question: exactly how much support/votes is required for a feature request to meet the "looks like it has community support" criterion? +7 is clearly not enough. Must the question reach +30 in a day in order to meet it?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you are getting a quantifiable answer on this question. That is not how the procedure was intended to work. Proof: suppose every [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) with at least 10 upvotes and at most 30% of that as downvotes in the first 24 hours after posting the question would qualify. If that was the case, they would have built an *automatic* flag for this. Or wait, even better: the Community user would tag it as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). Bugs don't get 10 upvotes if they can't be reproduced by others and questions which can be answered by the community here itself usually tend to get an answer quite quickly.

There's *no point* in taking away almost all moderators' discretion and making them what the Dutch call a *doorgeefluik*, a serving hatch, whose only purposes is to enable things to be transported from A (Meta) to B (the Employees). A question might be important (whatever that means) but fail to gather enough support in the form of its score because it's a delicate topic (I'm thinking about Code of Conduct related issues) or it might be a very funny bug which isn't too important but gets much upvotes because of the way it is written.

Note: this answer intentionally doesn't try to offer an explanation for the declined flag message. Perhaps other factors are at play, but there's a character limit for flag messages.