# Do new meta posts have to be within the current roadmap to be escalated for a [status-review] tag?

Tags: support, flags, meta

Just today, I had a couple flags of mine requesting that posts be escalated using the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag declined as they didn't align with the current [topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348643/377214) that are on the team's roadmap. The requests in question were filed within 24 hours of my flags.

As far as I've interpreted the [policy on staff escalation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/377214), the restriction that only requests about topics on the roadmap can be escalated only applies to *older* requests, not to *new* requests: *new* requests can be about *any* topic. Quoting from the criteria:

> ### New questions:
>
> For any *new question*, consider the following questions:
>
> - Is the question a feature request that looks like it has community support?
> - Is it a bug report that others have been able to reproduce?
> - Is the question only fully answerable by an employee?
>
> If you replied “yes” to **at least one** of the above, then that question is a good candidate for escalation.

Notice that it states "for *any* new question". The requests in question had earned 18 and 16 scores and hadn't received any downvotes at the time I had cast the flags, which to me looks like decent community support, meeting the first bullet.

The post also says the following:

> [...] we ask that you focus mostly on resurfacing **old** questions that relate to [...] things currently being worked on by the various product teams as part of their quarterly roadmaps

Added emphasis on "old". That combination of quotes leads me to believe that the topic policy on escalation only applies to *older* requests, not *new* ones. But my flags were still declined as the posts weren't in the roadmap.

Either one of the following is true:

- My interpretation of the escalation policy is incorrect.
- The moderator's interpretation of the escalation policy is incorrect.
- The moderator didn't notice that the requests were new.
- There was an internal staff note to moderators that the topic restrictions now do apply to new requests, and not only to older ones as they did before (prior flags of mine asking for new requests that didn't fit the roadmap to be escalated were marked helpful and processed at the time).

If one of the first two cases is true, I would appreciate a clarification from staff about it so that either I can refocus my flags, or so moderators have an explicit reference that they're supposed to action flags on such posts. If the third case is true, it would be nice if I either got a response that says I should more clearly indicate this in the flag, or if moderators would notice the dates these were filed. If the fourth case is true, I'd like if staff edited the public post to indicate so.

Why were the flags declined in this case?

**Update:** Tinkeringbell's answer states that another reason for the decline may be because 18 upvotes isn't considered enough community support. However, the reason for the decline that I received **very specifically** states that it was because it wasn't in the roadmap:

> declined - Popularity isn't a criteria for review. It should be within the current roadmap for the best chance for it to be picked up.

Comment: I saw a [tag:status-planned] getting its tag removed the other day, so it's not entirely clear what is and isn't required to get an issue resolved.

Comment: @Mast That was actually my request. That question was about the Android app, and since the team announced that no more code changes would be made to the app (i.e. they officially discontinued it), I thought it would be prudent if it weren't still tagged as planned, and the mod agreed.

Answer (score 3):

> Do new meta posts have to be within the current roadmap to be escalated for a [status-review] tag?

Simple answer: no. Your interpretation of the escalation policy to include new posts *is* correct.

> However, the reason for the decline that I received very specifically states that it was because it wasn't in the roadmap:

Then that reason was wrong or poorly phrased. I'll go try and figure out what happened there.

> Either one of the following is true:

What if *none* of the following there is true? We *did* notice that the post you flagged were new, we *are* aware of the guidelines for new posts and status-review tags, and we *do* read the flags we're handling. There's also been no conniving in secret rooms behind your back that changed the rules without letting you know.

You've come up with all sorts of contrived reasons for why this might have happened, but you're missing the most obvious option: **"Community support" isn't an easily quantifiable thing.** So the moderator that handled your flags (which wasn't me) was probably not misinterpreting the policy either, but just using a different set of quantifications.

You say the post you flagged have support, because of their score of 16/18 upvotes. But 16 or 18 votes on this site really isn't that much. Going with [one of my own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951) as an example, that one had 46 upvotes on the first day, and 4 more on the day it got its status-review tag. That to me says 'community support' much more obviously.

Unless 'community support' is properly quantified and those quantifications communicated, I'm guessing these situations will continue. I can't give you those quantification though, as I don't know them either.

Comment: I [have asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346787/exactly-how-much-support-is-required-for-a-feature-request-to-meet-the-criteria) about the requirement for community support before. That doesn't have a proper answer, so I see why you're also in the dark about it.

Comment: @Sonic Even for that feature-request of mine that *did* get a status-review tag, it turned out to be rather useless. As a moderator, I probably won't be too upset if both community support and bug that others can reproduce are scratched from that list: community support is just hard to determine and bugs are already tracked. I wouldn't mind sticking things to a.) posts related to the roadmap (be it new or old) and b.) things that only an employee can satisfactorily answer.

Comment: Some weeks later, did you figure out what happened here?